# code which is not working anymore

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This code was written and it was working for a couple of months. However, there was some Oracle updates a day before, and now this code is not working anymore. Basically, this code deletes the duplicates.

```
 delete from integration where rowid in (
     select rowid from (
          select rowid, intg.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY intg.pid ORDER BY intg.rowid DESC) rk
          from integration intg where pid||to_char(entry_date, 'dd.mm.yyhh:mi:ss') in (
               select pid||to_char(entry_date, 'dd.mm.yyhh:mi:ss') from integration
               group by pid, entry_date
               having count(pid) > 1
          )
     ) where rk = 1
);
```

When I execute this code then it just keeps executing. Yes, there are no duplicates so I should just get empty result instead of stucked into executing..Any ideas how I may fix this problem?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your sql has several steps. How long does this take to run?

```
select pid||to_char(entry_date, 'dd.mm.yyhh:mi:ss') 
from integration
group by pid, entry_date
having count(pid) > 1
```

And this?

```
select rowid, 
       intg.*, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY intg.pid ORDER BY intg.rowid DESC) rk
       from integration intg 
       where pid||to_char(entry_date, 'dd.mm.yyhh:mi:ss') in (select pid||to_char(entry_date, 'dd.mm.yyhh:mi:ss') 
                                                                 from integration
                                                                 group by pid, entry_date
                                                                 having count(pid) > 1
                                                                )
```

Is it possible that there are any other locks on the data that you are trying to delete? You can find information on locks in pl/sql developer with tools->sessions or using the dictionary tables e.g. v$lock

Comment: If you suspect a lock you could try and select the same rows for update nowait and it will immediately return if the rows are locked